# Possibility of CSRF-related issues in cached sign up form (Django)

Tags: django, caching, csrf

I have a sign up page in a Django project which I've cached (using `@cache_page(600)` on the view). On the page itself, I'm testing a simple form like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'sign_up' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Nickname:{{ form.username }}<br>
  Password:{{ form.password1 }}<br>
  Password (repeat):{{ form.password2 }}<br>
  <input class="btn bcg bs mlt mbs" type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

1) Would caching such a page cache the `CSRF` token as well?

2)And if it does, would that have a deleterious effect on user sign up in any way?

3) Moreover, what about security vulnerabilities?

Comment: This may help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#s-caching

Comment: `@csrf_protect` is the answer you are looking for...

Comment: @itzMEonTV: thanks for that reference. But I need clarity on one thing. Imagine the sign up template is rendered via `view1()`, whereas the `<form>` in the sign up template is posted to `view2()`. Now `view1()` has `@cache_page(600)`, whereas `view2()` has `@csrf_protect`. In this specific case, do I decorate `view1()` with `@csrf_protect` as well? And if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
@csrf_protect
```

Because if you use `cache middleware`, render updated contexts will not work if cache is available.That means csrf will not update in that case. So you need to explicitly do csrf_protect inorder to execute the `CsrfMiddleWare`

Comment: Thanks for this. Two other things I wanted to know apart from your answer are: **1)** since the POST request is being made to a different `view` (see my comment above), I'll just add `@csrf_protect` on this second view right? **2)** even if the `CSRF` token was cached, would it have any adverse effects on user sign up (I feel it won't)?

Comment: @csrf_protect should be on first view where you are are rendering form. So no need of csrf_protect in second view, because generally POST methods accepting views putting cache makes no sense.